# MERN Project ENV variables Error : Undefined

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, mern, development-environment, dotenv

In my MERN project I am not able to use ENV variables correctly, first of all while importing my MOGODB_URI is giving me this error :

```
The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, 
got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
```

and I also can't use other variables i have declared as well like PORT,JWT_SECRET,etc. When I try to console these it only returns undefined.

```
console.log(process.env.MONGODB_URI, process.env.PORT, process.env.NODE_ENV); //undefined undefined undefined
```

I am not able to get to the root to this error, I have been following best practices & making sure to import these modules, but the error is still there.

```
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
require('dotenv').config();
```

Please help provide solution, It will be a much help. I am attaching the photo for refference.[My Folder Structure & Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xm3Wn.png)

I have tried using a downgraded version of dotenv, but that didn't work. Also I have tried to import dotenv using different methods none of them is working . `const dotenv = require("dotenv"); require('dotenv').config();`

Comment: does it work if you run your code with `node -r dotenv/config your_script.js`? What is the content of your .env file? And where is your .env file located relative to the code file you are executing?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to see from your screenshot, but it looks like your only .env file is inside `frontend/`. dotenv finds the first .env file by going up the folder tree, but not into other folders on the same level. Try adding a .env file in `backend/` with the required variables.